# "ACPI\QEMU0001" unknown ACPI device after Windows 2008 install with libvirt

Tags: drivers, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

After installing Windows 2008 in a libvirt virtual environment (command below for reference), I'm stuck with an "Unknown device" in Device Manager. The `Hardware Ids` show `ACPI\QEMU0001`.

I tried using the drivers from the `virtio-win-0.1-74.iso` (required for Network and Disk in my case), but no luck.

```
virt-install --name=win2008 --ram=3072 --os-type=windows --vcpus=2 --os-variant=win2k8 --cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/images/6001.18000.080118-1840_amd64fre_Server_en-us-KRMSXFRE_EN_DVD.iso --disk path=/dev/mapper/vgHP-win2008,bus=virtio --network bridge=br0,model=virtio --vnc --noautoconsole
```

ACPI shutdown (through '# virsh shutdown') does seem to work.

I do have the proper ACPI entries in my domain's XML, from installation time onwards:

```
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
```

Windows cannot find drivers online either. Any idea on how to fix this?
Is it mandatory to fix, or can this be ignored?

I tried again without virtio drivers, i.e. a standard install with IDE, using following command:

```
    # virt-install --name=winserver --ram=3072 --os-type=windows --vcpus=2 --os-variant=win2k8 --cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/images/6001.18000.080118-1840_amd64fre_Server_en-us-KRMSXFRE_EN_DVD.iso --disk path=/dev/vgHP/winserver --network bridge=br0 --vnc --noautoconsole
```

Same behavior though - still an 'Unknown device'.

Comment: I think it might be an audio device.  Did a quick search on the hardware vendor id and got some hits about audio drivers.  Also, noticed that there is no audio device listed in device manger.

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 13.10 server + kvm. On XP guest i had unknovn device ACPI\QEMU0001\4&2C5A7332&0
Turns out it was VirtIO-Serial communication device.
Extracted driver from virtio-win-0.1-74.iso virtio-win\WXP

hope it helps someone.
;]